# MongoError: connect EMFILE - There is a way to tell Socket-io to kill the inactive connections?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

i'm facing a problem related with my nodeJS app and WebSocket using Socket-io.

After doing some tests with a couple of users i have been facing a problem with my server, because this error is generated:

```
MongoError: connect EMFILE 127.0.0.1:27017
```

After some research i found that error means error maximum files which indicates that the OS is denying my program to open more file descriptors. Then i looked at my server and using this line:

```
lsof -n -i -P | grep node
```

Shows a lot of connection and I am pretty sure that this happens because I'm sending realtime notifications using Socket-io

[image]

My theory is that all those notifications are staying open and therefore generating the EMF error, so my question is, How can I especify in my nodeJS code that the connections can't be active forever ? There is a way to tell Socket-io to kill the inactive connections ?

PD: Other similar posts suggest to increment the ulimit in the server, but i think thats not the correct solution.

Any thoughts ? Thanks.